# Best way to get osm.pbf data for a given extent?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, josm

I need to download/create a [PBF](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) file containing all osm data for several french urban areas. To select data, I have, for each urban area, the values of the attribute [ref:INSEE](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FR:Key:ref:INSEE?uselang=fr) for every city composing the area.

What could be the best method to do this?

I'm looking for an automatable method, for example by a script with a boundary filter as a parameter.

Geofabrik seems to have automatic tasks to do it for every regions, country and continent.

My environments are a windows local machine and a linux server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place for subsetted datasets is geofabrik IMHO.

The tool of choice, if you want to keep the data in PBF format is [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis)

It is a java Application and will run on Windows and Linux. I run mine on Windows 2008 R2 and Ubuntu Trusty.

Check Out [The Beginners Guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Beginner.27s_guide) I did not have too much trouble getting to grips with it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I finally have a linux script downloading XML data using OSM XAPI with a bounding box, then converting the XML to PBF using Osmosis.

Comment: Welcome, For me it is a lot more efficient on Linux than Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to osmosis you can try to use [osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) and [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) in your scripts. Availeable on both, WIN and Linux.

You can download a bigger country extract from geofabrik.de or other sources, and then do a kind of clipping with bounding boxes or maybe even polygon files.

Maybe there are even boundary relations which describe the exact administrative areas you are looking for.

Comment: the clipping based on a polygon sounds great, I will try this osmconvert, thanks.